# iOS - Packaging Multiple Apps

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, cross-platform

I am using a [chess asset from the Unity Asset Store](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/game-toolkits/chess-engine-ai-mobile-multiplayer-246295) and I've modified their UCI system that support starting, stopping, and communicating with other processs on Windows, Mac, Linux to also support Android in IL2CPP builds.

I just recently learnt that I can package multiple '.apk' files for release so on the Play Store I can package a build of 'Stockfish-UCI.apk' with 'MyChessGame.apk' and use my 'inter app communication manager' module and C# wrapper to send/receive UCI commands between the apps. Is there any way to do something similar for iOS or is this just simply not possible with iOS?

Comment: I know I can do a C++ 'wrapper' that lets me play Stockfish games using pinvoke and building Stockfish as a library for each platform but I would rather have support for any UCI engine I can build on the platforms if possible. This is the goal.